# Parsing XML in C# from SOAP response with header values

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have an xml response from a web service that has a bunch of headers I want to ignore. The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
    <ns2:retrieveCustomerResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.blah.neeg.com/">
     <customer>
        <details>
           <code>1000274</code>
             <customerNo>1000274</customerNo>
               <customerTypeRef>
                 <code>C</code>
```

and i have an object that I want to map this too that looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot("customer")]
public class Customer{
    [XmlElement("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
```

when I try and cast the xml to the object using this:

```
public static T CallWebService<T>(string req)
{
  ...calls web service and gets a response
  string soapResult;
  using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
    {
      using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
          soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

but when I try and cast it to the object type that is passed in:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
T returnObject = default(T);

try
  {
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(soapResult))
      {
        returnObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(ex);
   }

   return returnObject;
```

I catch the exception that:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 24). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> was not expected.
```

I thought that annotating the model would match the elements but it looks like it is struggling too parse the xml. Is there any way to ignore the headers and just look for the content that matched the tags?

I don't want to do a straight forward mapping because i want this call to be generic so I can pass any request and a corresponding object I want the response to be mapped to.

Comment: In your `Customer` class you have a `code` element, but that wouldn't map to your XML with the `XmlSerializer` as it is nested under a `details` element. Is that a mistake, or do you expect a custom mapping all the way down, not just skipping headers?

Comment: Hi. Even if I put another class underneath to have the corrected nested hierarchy this still throws the error as per before. [XmlRoot("customer")]
    public class Customer{
        [XmlElement("details")]
        public Details Details {  get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        [XmlElement("code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you load the response stream in an XDocument instead of a string you can use LINQ to XML to query the XML. This way you can skip the parent elements and access the customer element(s) and serialize these to object(s).

```
    XDocument soapResult;
    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            soapResult = XDocument.Load(rd);
        }
    }

    //should be modified to your needs
    var unwrappedResponse = soapResult.Descendants((XNamespace)"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" + "Body").First().FirstNode;
```

Consuming SOAP webservices is a lot easier if you use a service reference or at least have access to an XSD as you can then generate classes automatically.

Comment: thanks. I did try going down the route of using XDocument instead but I ran into problems casting that to my object. How can I cast the unwrappedResponse into the object passed in?

Comment: I also tried creating a service reference which generated the classes for me but they were still throwing errors. I could see the raw response coming back but the objects were null